# query db for date time more than today

Tags: php, sql, datetime

i have a table where i am storing my expiry date like thi:

```
| id |   expire_date    |
| 2  | 2019-09-19T15:34 |
```

and i want to query the table with todays date and time and onwards so far this is what i got;

```
date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Fiji");
$now = date('Y-m-d\TH:i');
"SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE $now > `expire_date`"
```

but this does not work .

the is not a sql injection problem.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE expire_date > '$now'"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add column name after the `WHERE` clause not after greater than symbol `>`

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE expire_date >= '$now'"
```

For the reference you can visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)